# ASP.Button - OnClientClick firing incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have a asp.net button and I am using OnclientClick to close the window

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancelSomething" runat="server" class="type-button" 
                    Text="Cancel"  OnClientClick = "Javascript:self.close()" 
                    onclick="btnCancelSomething_Click"/>
```

the onclick event does nothing and I am planning to remove it. However, when I click the button the first time it is loading the page again. I click the button again then the script is fired.

How to make the window close the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the button isn't going to have any server-side functionality behind it anyway, why make it an `asp:Button` at all?  A regular button will do the trick just fine:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="type-button" onclick="self.close()" />
```

That way it's purely client-side, since that's all the functionality that's needed anyway.  It won't cause any "post-back" unnecessarily.

You could even take it a step further and break apart markup from functionality:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="type-button" id="cancelButton" />
```

Then in a `script` tag elsewhere, or in a separate file:

```
$('#cancelButton').click(function() {
  self.close();
});
```

(Of course, this example assumes jQuery.  But then what doesn't?  The separation of markup and functionality if the key point here, though.  How you achieve it, even how you identify the element with an `id` as in my example or some other way, is up to you.)

Comment: That makes perfect sense! To be honest with you, I didn't even think about it. Thank you.

Comment: @kalls: I'm glad someone finally made use of my avid proponency of pure markup over ASP.NET server controls.  It's often a losing battle for me :)